# Opening files in a server with codeigniter/php

Tags: php, file, codeigniter, header

**What I want to do:** Have the user click a link, it goes to a function also with a GET for file ext and file id(id is what it is named on the server). That function then opens that file in a new tab or downloads it if it cant be opened.

**What I've Tried:** Codeigniters read_file() function. 
     Also:

```
 header('Content-type: application/pdf');

 header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="1.pdf"');

 readfile('1.pdf');
```

but that doesn't work. Or it does and i dont know how to configure it properly.

**Where the files are:** There is a folder named uploads. The uploads and the application folder for codeigniter are on the same level.

I'm using codeigniter. The files are either, gif, jpg, or pdf. Thanks

Comment: The header? It doesnt download the file. It just downloads a pdf with the name 1 and when i try to open it, i get and error saying its broken or something.

Comment: header seems to be correct. I don't believe you it throws error saying sentence "it's broken or something" :) try other browsers, maybe just some PDF plugin opens file in browser instead of downloading file with "save as" option. sorry for my enlgish

Comment: Yeah the pdf ive been testing with turns out to be broken so once i get a working one we will see what works. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want a new window:

```
echo "<script language='text/javascript'>
        window.open('" . $filepath . "');
      </script>";
```

or just a redirect:

```
echo "<script language='text/javascript'>
        document.location = '" . $filepath . "';
     </script>";
```

Comment: No because if possible i want it to open in the users browser. Wont thatjust download?

Comment: Would the file path need to go back two folders since that is in application/controllers?

Comment: Also would that download if it wasnt viewable?

Comment: Just use absolute path like `"http://www.mysite.com/".$myfile` or use the `base_url($myfile)` function

Comment: And the answer to your second question is, yes. that's the browser behaviour, not the scripts.

Comment: So i tried 

     redirect(base_url('uploads/1.pdf'));
but it just said failed to load pdf document.

Comment: Ok, so apparently all the pdfs on my server are broken. The one ive been testing with is too so im gonna go get a working one and try this.